# Multiview app. cannot change text field values

Tags: iphone, objective-c

hey guys i'm making an app that has 2 views. the first view is where the user inputs the numbers and when they hit calculate button.. its takes them to a new view where the answer is displayed on a textfield. the calculation is handled by a different file. "calc.h " and "calc.m"

this is the main view files (the view where the user enters the numbers )

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface test2ViewController : UIViewController {


    IBOutlet UITextField *num1; //input number 1
    IBOutlet UITextField *num2; // input number2
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) UITextField *num1;
@property(nonatomic, retain)UITextField *num2;

-(IBAction)calculate:(id)sender; //the calculate button
-(IBAction)exit:(id)sender;
@end
```

the answer is displayed in a different view that shows up when the user hits the calculate button. below is the code for that !

```
#import "test2ViewController.h"
#import "answer.h"
#import "calculate.h"
@implementation test2ViewController

@synthesize num1,num2;

-(IBAction)calculate:(id)sender{
    calculate *testclass = [[calculate alloc]init];
    answer *view = [[answer alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:view animated:YES];
    int i = [[num1 text] intValue];
    testclass.number1 = i;

    int j = [[num2 text] intValue];
    testclass.number2 = j;
    [testclass calc];



}
```

".h" file of the view that displays the answer

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface answer : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UITextField *text;//textfield to display answer 

}
@property(nonatomic,retain) UITextField *text;
-(IBAction)back:(id)sender;

@end
```

".m" file

```
#import "answer.h"
#import "test2ViewController.h"
#import "calculate.h"

@implementation answer

@synthesize text;

-(IBAction)back:(id)sender{

    test2ViewController *view = [[test2ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:view animated:YES];

}
```

the next is an objective c class file that does the calculation. it has one function that does the calculation and here is the ".h" and ".m" file 
".h"

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface calculate : NSObject {

    int number1;
    int number2;
    NSString *ans;
}
@property int number1;
@property int number2;
@property (nonatomic , retain) NSString *ans;
-(void)calc;
@end
```

".m"

```
#import "calculate.h"
#import "answer.h"
#import "test2ViewController.h"
@implementation calculate

@synthesize number1,number2,ans;

-(void)calc{

int i = number1 + number2;
    answer *ans1 = [[answer alloc]init];

    ans = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]; 
    ans1.text.text = ans;


}


@end
```

so as you can see the above function calculates the answer..puts it into a string and sets that to the textfield. but the textfield doesn't show anything..so the problem here is that i cannot access the textfield even though i created an object from it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im a bit confused to what your trying to accomplish, do you want to use an NSString or the text UITextField in another class? If thats the case give the string that is carrying whatever you want to be displayed a `@property`, then set whatever you want the strings value to it, next import the `calc.h` (`#import "calc.h"`) in the second class, then in the interface create this `calc *getString;` create a `@property` for that, `@synthesize` it. Then to get the value of the string from calc do something like this `getString.SomeStringName`, now you are able to do whatever you want with it.

I think this is what you want? if not feel free to comment. Good Day :)

Edit: Im going to give you an example because this is a bit confusing the way i wrote it lol

So here is your calc.h file, also remember im typing this online and not in xcode, so if i spell something wrong or make a simple mistake, thats why:

```
@interface calc : UIViewController { 

NSString *answer;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *answer;

@end
```

Your .h could have more

Now lets hop into your .m

```
@implementation calc
@synthesize answer;

//do all the work to get the answer, once you have it do this
[answer retain];


//load your new view controller
```

Lets hop into your other view controller that will be loaded

this is .h file of it

```
#import "calc.h"

@interface secondController : UIViewController {

calc *getAnswer;


}
@property (nonatomic, retain) calc *getAnswer;

@end
```

Then go to your .m

```
@implementation secondController

@synthesize getAnswer;

-(void)viewDidLoad{

WhateverYouWantTheStringToBeSetTo.text = getAnswer.Answer;

}
```

This should then grab the string from the other controller and allow you to use it in this one..

Hope this helps :)

Comment: i tried your method and it doesn't seem to work.. i have edited the post with my code.

Comment: Oh i see what your trying to do. Although lots of it doesnt make much sense. So the variable that the final answer goes into is the `ans1`?

Comment: ans1 is an object created from the answer.h .. in answer.h there is a UItextfield named text..'ans1.text.text = ans'.. is setting the text of UItextfield to ans (which is the final answer ! ) xD thats what i'm trying to do .. but for some reason it won't wrk.. in a nut shell this is what i'm trying to do.. input numbers in view1 do the calculation in a different file. and when a button is presssed display the answer in a different view !

Comment: Ahh i see what your doing, so calculation is being done i a completely different class? why would you do that? just do it in the same class, get the answer and then transfer the answer to the other view. It would be much more ideal.

Comment: its not one calculation.. i did this one as a test .. my plan was to make an interface in a different class and use that to calculate. there are 3 different calculations that are being done.. and there are few variables that keep repeating in all of these..isn't it the best practice to make an interface and then using it rather than doing it all in one big class ? xD

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your "ans" `UIViewController` did not load yet.

The most standard way to do this is to give your `UIViewController` "ans" a `@property` with the result. Then in the "ans" `viewDidLoad` method, set the text field to the appropriate value.